# Removing North arrow?

Tags: qgis, north-arrow

I use QGIS and don't know why there is a North indicator (see the figure).

Anyone know how did it come and how to remove it?

[image: example]

Answer (score 3):

In the menus, go to View -> Decorations -> North Arrow, and disable it.

Comment: thanks so much. It is the right way.